# Override border CSS into individual borders under Custom CSS in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

As far as I know, I can only disable a CSS property by overriding them under Custom CSS. The current CSS border is,

```
.pewc-column-wrapper .pewc-checkbox-image-wrapper {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

I want to remove the border property and replace it with individual top, right, bottom ones. The below doesn't work. Any other ideas?

```
.pewc-column-wrapper .pewc-checkbox-image-wrapper {
    border-top: 4px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: ...but note that your second code snippet **doesn't actually change anything** from the previous setting.

Comment: This is odd, the original style is `4px solid transparent`, and you want to override with `4px solid transparent`? Same same?

Comment: If you read my question properly, I want to only have borders for top right and bottom but NOT left.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below.

```
.pewc-column-wrapper .pewc-checkbox-image-wrapper {
    border-top: 4px solid transparent !important;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent !important;
}
```

Or try replacing border with padding. Like below.

```
.pewc-column-wrapper .pewc-checkbox-image-wrapper {
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border-color:red green blue yellow;
```

in your case,

```
border-color:transparent transparent transparent transparent;
```